# ComErrorException 'Class Not Registered'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, com, integration-testing, merge-replication

I'm trying to write a integration(unit) test that calls an object from SQLServer Replication dll.

When it tries to instanciate the object `MergeSynchronizationAgent` i get an exception:

```
'{Class Not Registered}'
-2147221164
```

I tried switching the platform to x86 but that didn't work.

The exact dll is `Microsoft.SQLServer.Replication.dll`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure sql server was installed correctly on that machine? I doubt you would have to register any of the core com objects manually. Did you copy the file form somewhere else? Any way there is this Regsrvr32 function that might help.

Comment: lol. Yes SQL was installed correctly. This has been tried on multiple computers with same result. I don't know if its a Regsver32 problem, that was my hope to find a solution when I posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to make sure the object is registered--the ProgId and the CLSID are in the registry.  Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and search for the ProgId of the object if you know it.  If you don't know it, search for the CLSID in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID if it's a 64-bit DLL and in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID if the DLL is a 32-bit DLL.  Your process needs to be the same bit-ness as the DLL you want to load through COM.

Have you called CoInitialize() or OleInitialize() before you try to create the object? (If calling from .NET, should not have to call it)